# Pass a parameter to f:event listener

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, metadata, event-listener

I have the following event of preRenderView type to execute a method before loading the page:

```
<f:event listener="#{aprobacionFlujoController.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
```

I need to send a parameter to that listener, which is the best way to do it, probe as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{aprobacionFlujoController.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:attribute name="myid" value="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

Controller

```
public void retrieveData(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    String id = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myid");
}
```

But getAttributes() method returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are using JSF 2.2 then you can use the `<f:viewAction />` to perform tasks before page is rendered since what you are trying to achieve from what I can tell is to retrieve data from DB to display, in other words to have a dynamic web page.

In your facelets page:

```
<h:head>
  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="parameter_id" value="#{yourbean.searchId}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{yourbean.getInfo}" />
  </f:metadata>
</h:head>
```

What the `viewParam` does is to set the property passed in the `value` attribute; this property comes as an HTTP GET REQUEST parameter, e.g:

```
yourwebsite.com/yourpage.xhtml?parameter_id=parameter_value
```

In your *Managed Baen* you just have a method that performs the data extraction using the property:

```
@NAmed
@your_scope
public class YourBean implements Serializable{

   private String searchId;

   public void getInfo(){
     yourService.getData(searchId);
    // ... the rest .... 
  }

 // setter & getter for searchId
}
```

If you want to do it your way, asuming its because you're using JSF 2.1 | 2.0 then maybe try this to get the request parameters:

```
String parameter = ((Map<String,String>)Facescontext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()).get("your_parameter_name");
```